# C# - How does DataFormats.GetDataFormat work?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to figure out Drag And Drop using the features in the FluidKit.

I downloaded the Demo app and both the drag and drop have this line of code in it:

```
private static DataFormat SupportedFormat = DataFormats.GetDataFormat("FluidKit");
```

What is this doing?  I don't see anywhere that the format that is being gotten is set.  How does it know what it being gotten?

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DataFormat is just describing the type of object that is being dropped on your control. For instance, if you drag a couple of items from a ListView onto some other ListView you could check to be sure the data format you're receiving is "System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[]". If you receive a DataFormat that your control can't handle, then you can just choose to cancel the drop event, or prompt the user, etc.